HCE random uuid
I am emulating an NFC card, but there is a problem in the form of sending random UUID mifareClassic cards to the terminal. By the manufacturer, they are hardwired into a specific memory cell, but for security reasons, HCE does not allow the UUID to be taken from there and sends a random UUID for each operation. I'm in stupor. I saw similar questions here, but they are super old. I don’t even know which direction to dig in order to get around this without root or mifareCard flashing?
Under no circumstances should you root your phone. There is no way to reflash payment terminals. There is no way to reflash mifare classic cards. I tried to look at other applications that work with HCE, but the source code is closed, and there are no comments on the work

As already answered by @Andrew, a Mifare Classic NFC tag cannot be emulated by a "locked" = "not unrooted" Android device. If you emulated e.g. a Mifare DESFire Ex tag, there is a dedicated command to get the "real" tag UID. If a card reader uses this command, it would get the requested UID from a "real" tag and from your emulated one (you have to implement this method on your own, of course :-).

@MichaelFehr, thank bro

Random ID is as designed as NFC!=RFID. NFC was not designed to need a Globally Unique ID, there just needs to be a difference in ID between all Tags in the short field range.
It is also a security feature that it is Random.
Also on Android it only emulates a NFC Type 4a Tag which is totally different to mifareClassic card and Type 4a Tags don't have "memory cells".
What you are trying to do is not possible (in Android without heavily modifying the OS)
